# After Oversamling Smote With IsolationForest my result doesnt improve

Tags: machine-learning, imbalanced-data, imblearn, oversampling, isolation-forest

my dataset
test is 0    17565
1     2435
train is 0    70212
1     9788
I applied oversampling Smote with IsolationForest algorithm on just training set
before oversampling results:
F1 Score :
0.9278732648748262
Accuracy Score :
0.93025
Classification Report :
precision    recall  f1-score   support

```
       0       0.95      0.97      0.96     17648
       1       0.74      0.63      0.68      2352
```

after oversampling results:
F1 Score :
0.8172379348236138
Accuracy Score :
0.83115
Classification Report :
precision    recall  f1-score   support

```
       0       0.89      0.93      0.91     17648
       1       0.18      0.13      0.15      2352
```

my code is:

```
clf=IsolationForest(n_estimators=50, max_samples='auto', 
contamination=float(0.1),max_features=1.0)
clf.fit(X_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
y_pred[y_pred == 1] = 0
y_pred[y_pred == -1] = 1
```

These results are normal? Because ı think after oversampling resuts must be improved. Could you help me?
Best regards.